# Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a docker image on my ubuntu 18.04 machine and I have located **requirements.txt** in the same building directory but still its showing up this error.

> Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
> The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1

*requirements.txt is to install python modules using pip3.*

**requirement.txt:**

> numpy opencv-contrib-python opencv-python scikit-image pillow imutils
> scikit-learn matplotlib progressbar2 beautifulsoup4 pandas matplotlib
> re2 regex json argparse pickle

**DockerFile:**

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.1-cudnn7-runtime-ubuntu18.04

COPY requirements.txt /home/usr/app/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /home/usr/app/

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip sudo
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter
```

Comment: please, provide a full docker file

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I suspect that you haven't copied over your requirements.txt file to your Docker image.

Typically you add the following lines to your Dockerfile to copy your requirements.txt file and install it using pip:

```
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN python3 -m pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
```

If you don't explicitly copy over anything to your Docker image your image has no data save for what is on the base image.

Comment: Thanks,it worked. But now I'm facing new issue 
`Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-9s4fxvhr/opencv-python/`
`The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1`
I'm new to docker so can't figure out how to fix this.

Comment: If you can change your original question to include your Dockerfile and your requirements.txt file we can have  a better look at what is going on.

Comment: Done. And I'm not quite sure if I can use 2 base images. I want to merge 2 images to use in a single container.